# R Function to take a string from a set of characters to the end

Tags: r, string

I am just trying to take the end of some file names, all of which start with 20. This means I am trying to take the rest of the string after the 20, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

##### creating some dummy file names

`file_names <- c("20file_name1", "20filename_20")`

##### removing the targeted string using relpacement

`fixed_file_names <- sub("^20", "", file_names)`